# Winkler algorithm usage for web-forms

Tags: algorithm, jaro-winkler

From a web form client sends me many variables such as name, surname, id, adress etc. Sometimes user sends me name like;

```
Elviz Aaronn Presley
```

With Winkler algorithm, i want to compare all records with DB records.

1. Elvis will be compared to 'Elviz'
2. Aaron wll be compared to 'Aaronn'
3. Presley will be compared to Presley

Then Winkler will return me a value. for first and second cases it will return value more than 90. And its okey. When it comes to names like

```
Elviszfd Aaronn Presley
```

First case point will be less than 90. And it's not acceptable. But when i compare to with middle name and get average of all three. Point will be raised over 90 again. And i want to accept it.

Is it good and right practise to use winkler algorithm? Or should i choose another algorithm to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Jaro Winkler is in general a good solution for name comparison and it does reasonably well, 
but I would also consider *Monge-Elkan String Comparison* and *SoftTFIDF*.

[Here is a paper](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pradeepr/papers/ijcai03.pdf) describing the performance as well as time/space complexity of these approaches.